# Non-usual use of L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: real-analysis

I have a very specific doubt about L'Hôpital's rule, from reading a recent paper by Lauermann & Wolinsky in the Jan 2016 Econometrica ("Search with adverse selection".)

The authors were explaining the relationship between two likelihood functions, and they tell the reader to: "note that for any random variable $y$ with c.d.f. $G$, the expression $\frac{y}{-ln(1-G(y))}$ behaves like the inverse hazard rate $\frac{1-G}{g}$ for $y \to \infty$ (by L'Hôpital's rule)."

To be quite honest, I got stuck at this part. I simply could not see where L'Hôpital's rule applies in this case, much less derive this result. This text I quoted is part of an explanation, in general terms, of the following equality presented in the text, which is also claimed to be a result of L'Hôpital's rule:

$$\lambda_{w,\hat{w}}=\lim_{x \to \underline{x}} \frac{\frac{f_{w}(x)}{f_{\hat{w}}(x)}}{-\ln F_{w}(x)}=\lim_{x \to \underline{x}} \frac{-\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{f_{w}(x)}{f_{\hat{w}}(x)})}{\frac{f_{w}(x)}{F_{w}(x)}}$$

where $\underline{x}$ is the lower bound of $x$, $w < \hat{w}$, $F_{i}(y)$ is the c.d.f. of $y$ for individual $i$ and $f_{i}(y)$ is its derivative (the p.d.f.).

I appreciate all the help I can get, and look forward to interesting discussions regarding this (for me unusual) way to use L'Hôpital's rule.

Best,
Doug

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(y)$ be the probability density function (i.e. $G'(y)$), As $y \to \infty$ the numerator and denominator of the fraction go to infinity (the numerator obviously; the denominator because the logarithm of a tiny positive number is a very large negative number). So the hypotheses of L'Hopital apply (namely, the fraction is indeterminate, i.e. of the form $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$).

The derivative of the numerator is $1$, and the derivative of the denominator (chain rule) is
$$
\frac{1}{1-G(y)} \cdot g(y),
$$
so L'Hopital says the limit is the same as the limit of
$$
\frac{1-G(y)}{g(y)}
$$
as claimed in the book.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. It was as clear as possible and helped me a lot!